# transform-zoom-out does not keep the content centered

Tags: css, transform

I'm currently having a problem with a page I'm working on. I have a nice grid with different content blocks on them.

When I click on a block I open a modal, and the grid zooms out. I'm adding this class to my grid to zoom-out:

```
#container.overlay-open {
 transform: translate3d(0,0,-1500px);
}
```

The css of the container itself:

```
#container {
.transition(0.7s all);
transform-style: preserve-3d;
position: absolute;
left: 0px;
right: 0px;
top: 100px;
bottom: 100px;
}
```

This works perfectly for the first row. However when I scroll down a bit and click on an other block the grid-container keeps zooming out, but the container is moved a bit to the top of the screen, it's not centered anymore (picture 3).

How can I keep the content centered after zooming (picture 2)?

[image]

Comment: Please provide a minimal demo for us to directly see the effects outselves

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using "translate3d", you could use "scale". I believe that should achieve your desired effect.

```
#container.overlay-open {
    transform: scale(0.5);
}
```